# How do I get a long-term API OAuth token?

Tags: marketing-cloud, oauth2, fuel-sdk

I have some scheduled tasks that need to run for my Marketing Cloud app, and the 20-minute expiration on tokens causes problems.  I can refresh, but it has to refresh a *lot*.  And if two processes both try to refresh the same token, one wins and the other becomes irrecoverably defunct.  Is there a longer token or an easier way?

Comment: We have a setup page for our app that allows the user to provide oAuth authentication token which is stored in a protected custom setting (Allowed via SF). The app then uses that token to perform what it needs to do and is good until revoked. You also need to set up a connected app as well.

Comment: @Eric Can you point me to the page or documentation for this?  Will this work to operate as a user of the app, rather than as the owner account of the app itself?

Comment: Yes, it will run as the user that granted permission (IIRC): https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com - Posting as answer in case it was what you are looking for. Down vote it if it is not and I will remove the answer

Comment: It'll take some time to digest all that, but thanks!  Will this all work through the Ruby FuelSDK if I just set the `internal_token`, `access_token`, `refresh_token`, `auth_token_expiration` fields?

Answer (score 2):

We have a setup page for our app that allows the user to provide oAuth authentication token which is stored in a protected custom setting (Allowed via SF). The app then uses that token to perform what it needs to do and is good until revoked. You also need to set up a connected app as well.

it will run as the user that granted permission (IIRC): https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

Comment: Do you know if this page/information/answer is also relevant to ExactTarget (aka Salesforce Marketing Cloud) connected apps?

Comment: @ScottStafford - Not sure I understand the question. It is up to ET how they handle obtaining and storing the access tokens

Comment: Hmm.. I don't understand, but let me try asking another way. The link you gave, about "Digging Deeper into OAuth.. on Force.com".  Is that valid documentation for exacttargetapps or is that a completely unrelated salesforce.com oauth implementation?  I only am trying to get ET stuff to work, I don't know much about the rest of "force.com".

Comment: @ScottStafford - The link is all about oAuth2 in the context of the force.com platform

Comment: Agreed - and so my question boils down to, is the force.com platform the same as the ExactTarget/Salesforce Marketing Cloud one?  They're both salesforce.com sites, but maybe have independent histories...

Comment: ET / Marketing cloud is still salesforce, just with ET installed and possibly different licensing. But yes, they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

The oauth token expire time depends on session settings in salesforce instance

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_sessions.htm&language=en_US

IF your administrator is ready to increase this time through simple configuration then you should consider that option .

If your org has sensitive data then your system administrator might keep it at low value .

Please see screenshot for session time out value

[image]

Comment: I don't see any OAuth or token settings on that help page - should I?

Comment: I have added the picture to help you.Its in Session Settings page